# pound sign and shift-tilde in aterm

Tags: xterm, lxterminal

I'm having an issue with aterm whereby typeing the pound sign (shift+3) gives me 'Å£', and shift-tilde gives 'Å¬'. These keys are the only two which don't work properly. Interestingly they work absolutely fine in Xterm and lxterminal...

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your aterm is configured with iso-8859-1 as charset, better make it use utf-8.

Comment: Hmmm... Do you know if I can do that? All the info I can find re aterm and utf-8 support is from begore 2006 saying that there is none... Might have to move over to urxvt.

Comment: From http://www.afterstep.org/aterm.php: aterm is deprecated and in a maintenance mode only; there will be no further updates. Use rxvt-unicode instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help - I've made the switch and everything works fine now (also some nagging issues I had with colours in cmus are fixed :) )